# WinDBG: how to update exe without workspace unload

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, windbg

for some reason, I have to use windbg, the usage is a similar to IDE integrated debugger, so the typical process is a amend a source in editor, build, debug in windbg.
I've also customized windbg with own workspace settings.

however, if I stop the debugging it unloads exe from workspace and I need to open exe each time of the debug.

is there ability , like in VS debugger, to start/stop debug process without exe unload?
you see I need to stop the debug to update exe on the build

Comment: What type of workspace is it? There is a base workspace, user mode workspace and per-executable workspace. If you have not created a per-executable workspace, a `.detach` might be sufficient (not tried)

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2010/05/07/uncovering-how-workspaces-work-in-windbg.aspx if you want to understand WinDbg workspaces

Comment: thank you! that is what I was looking for

Comment: looks like I can't use other than per-executeable workspace because user-mode workspace requires to attach to already started exe. it's nto useful for step-by-step debugging of typical user applciations. in other hand , still not unclear how to update loaded exe